# Missing left parenthesis

Tags: oracle, parentheses

Missing left parenthesis on line 9..can't see the error!

```
create table EDITIONS(  
        ID number NOT NULL,  
        ID_VOLUME number,               
        Publishing varchar2(20),                
        Year number(4),                 
        Language varchar2(10),              
        Pages number(4),        
        CONSTRAINT  pk_editions PRIMARY KEY,        
        constraint  fk_editions_volume foreign key (id_volume)
                references volume(id),  
        constraint  editions_publishing,  
        constraint  editions_year,  
        constraint  editions_language,  
        constraint  editions_pages,  
);
```

Comment: You have an extra comma on the last row of the definition for `editions_pages`.  Of course, the constraints aren't defined either and that would be causing problems too.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
create table EDITIONS (
    ID number NOT NULL primary key
    ID_VOLUME number,
    Publishing varchar2(20),
    Year number(4),
    Language varchar2(10),
    Pages number(4),
    constraint fk_editions_volume foreign key (id_volume) references volume(id)
);
```

I assume you are using `Oracle` because of the `varchar2()`.  You should tag questions with the correct database.